# phpmyadmin convert all empty fields to NULL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

is it possible to convert all `empty fields` in a database table to `NULL`.

one: without using a script to do it. meaning within myphpadmin?

if thats not possible

two: what would a script in php look like?

Thank you.

EDIT, this is after a database has already been created, with over 3000 rows.

Comment: three: have you tried researching it?

Comment: @hamza, meaning is there an option that automatically does this?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = NULL
WHERE my_column = '';
```